# How do I set open file limits for a systemd slice

Tags: azure, systemd

I'm trying to increase the open file descriptors limit for a transient scope (`enable_e0d20b64-6e48-4e38-a718-6ae53745eddb.scope`), but I'm not able to.

Here's the hierarchy of the slice and scope units:

```
├─azure.slice
│ ├─waagent.service
│ │ ├─18305 /usr/bin/python -u /usr/sbin/waagent -daemon
│ │ ├─27946 python -u bin/WALinuxAgent-2.9.0.4-py2.7.egg -run-exthandlers
│ │ ├─28127 /bin/bash /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.ManagedServices.ApplicationHealthLinux-1.0.5/bin/applicationhealth-shim enable
│ │ ├─28129 tee -ia /var/log/azure/applicationhealth-extension/handler.log
│ │ └─28144 /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.ManagedServices.ApplicationHealthLinux-1.0.5/bin/applicationhealth-extension enable
│ └─azure-vmextensions.slice
│   └─azure-vmextensions-Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent.DependencyAgentLinux_9.10.13.19190.slice
│     └─enable_e0d20b64-6e48-4e38-a718-6ae53745eddb.scope
│       ├─18431 /bin/sh /opt/microsoft/dependency-agent/bin/microsoft-dependency-agent-manager
│       └─18515 /opt/microsoft/dependency-agent/bin/microsoft-dependency-agent
```

I have tried adding an override at 'azure.slice', but it doesn't look slices support the `LimitNOFILE` directive.

`$ systemctl cat azure.slice`

```
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/azure.slice

[Unit]
Description=Slice for Azure VM Agent and Extensions
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=slices.target

# /etc/systemd/system/azure.slice.d/override.conf
[Slice]
LimitNOFILE=4096
```

*Error*

```
Jan 04 17:14:48 mq01.####.onmicrosoft.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/azure.slice.d/override.conf:2] Unknown lvalue 'LimitNOFILE' in section 'Slice'
```

`systemctl cat azure.slice`

```
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/azure.slice

[Unit]
Description=Slice for Azure VM Agent and Extensions
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=slices.target

# /etc/systemd/system/azure.slice.d/override.conf
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=4096
```

*Error*

```
Jan 04 17:23:03 mq01.####.onmicrosoft.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/azure.slice.d/override.conf:1] Unknown section 'Service'. Ignoring.
```

`systemd.resource-control` doesn't show anything that would be applicable to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open file limits are a per-process rlimit, not a cgroup option, so they cannot be set at slice level.

Unlike transient services, a transient scope is usually created with existing processes (i.e. ones that were spawned directly by some other service or app), so you should instead raise LimitNOFILE= on the parent – which I'm assuming is `waagent.service` – and the new limit will be inherited by all of its child processes, regardless of their later placement in the cgroup tree.

Comment: Right, that's why I added an output of systemd-cgls to show the hierarchy. The process I need to modify the open file limits is a scope of a slice. There are no parent services.

Comment: My point was that the cgroup hierarchy **does not matter.** What matters is the process parent-child hierarchy, which isn't reflected by cgls (indeed that's the whole purpose of .scope units – to allow moving a child process into another cgroup). The process was spawned by _something_ (not by systemd, as systemd only starts processes for .services, not for .scopes), so use something like `ps axf` or `htop` to find the parent process of 18431 and then find which cgroup it's in.

Comment: I think I now understand (hopefully). In my example the process was initiated by something else and then assigned to azure.slice for cgroup assignment (something like `systemd-run --scope -p Slice=azure-vmextensions-Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent.DependencyAgentLinux_9.10.13.19190.slice --unit enable_e0d20b64-6e48-4e38-a718-6ae53745eddb /opt/microsoft/dependency-agent/bin/microsoft-dependency-agent-manager`. NOFILE was then inherited from whatever process ran `systemd-run`, so I need to identify that process. Thanks for the explanation, it took me a while to understand.